# WCF REST service results in 404

Tags: wcf, rest

I have read most of the WCF REST 404 posts but none that helped me...

I have built a WCF REST service successfully. However, now it is causing issues. I tried just creating a sample WCF REST service and I cannot get this to work without using the .SVC.

This is what I have in my code

```
 [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {
        [WebGet(UriTemplate="data")]
        [OperationContract]
        string GetData();
    }

 public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        public string GetData()
        {
            return "1";
        }
    }
```

and this is what I have in my web.config

```
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="Default" name="RESTService.Service1">
        <endpoint address="http://mydomain:8888/Service1.svc" 
                  binding="webHttpBinding" 
                  contract="RESTService.IService1" 
                  behaviorConfiguration="Web" />
        <endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpBinding" address="mex" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="Default">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="Web">
        <webHttp />
      </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
  </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

When I go to `http://mydomain:8888/data` is responds in 404. Any ideas why it is not hitting the GetData() function? The following URL works if I remove the Endpoint address

```
http://mydomain:8888/Service1.svc/data
```

However, I want the address to be `http://mydomain:8888/data`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try leaving your web config in the version you have working correctly (with the svc in the path) and add route table entries during application start in the global asax file

check this out for more info

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668177.aspx